# How to add the 'localhost' in Google Cloud Platform as an authorized domain for OAuth2

Tags: google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0, dns, verifyerror

## Question:

How do I add the Google Cloud public facing localhost to the authorized domains list so I can set up OAuth?

## Background

I'm trying to follow this Google Dev tutorial on [Building a Node.js Web App using Google Cloud Platform](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-nodejs).

Some of the instructions seem slightly out of date, but I've managed to work around it so far. On Page 9, In section 'Setting OAuth 2.0 Client' step 9 (listed below) it says to paste in the URL `https://8080-dot-<9 digit number>-dot-devshell.appspot.com/` with my 9 digit number replaced:

[image]

## Problem

When I paste in the URI, I'm told that the URI needs to be added to the authorized domains list:

[image: Authorized redirect URIs - Invalid Redirect]

While that's not in the instructions, I went ahead and did as instructed. But every time it goes to 'verify' the domain, it keeps getting a rejection screen saying:

[image: Webmaster Central - Verification Failed]

So what on earth do I do here? It won't let me make the OAuth key without the verified domain, and it won't let me verify the domain.

Comment: So I'm not totally sure what happened, but I created the OAuth 2.0 token without a Redirect URI and then added it afterwards, and it let me. It's a good workaround, but I'm curious to know what went wrong.

Comment: `localhost` is not a public endpoint - this is an internal loopback address. You cannot use domains that you do not own/control. You can use localhost for testing with a local webserver and browser, but you cannot use that to deploy as localhost is not reachable from the public Internet.

Comment: It's not a true `localhost`, as what it appears to be doing is connecting `localhost:8080` to `https://8080-dot-<9 digit number>-dot-devshell.appspot.com/` I have full control of that URL one the user is authed.

Comment: You have no control over the `...dot-devshell.appspot.com` domain. You need to use domains that you own/control.

Comment: How am I supposed to do the tutorial - is it just broken now?

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing the "[...]-dot-devshell.appspot.com" url in 2017 used to forward directly to the web server you wanted to test.

This must have changed in the meantime to require authentication before accessing the web page. This is blocking the configuration of the OAuth since the URL redirects to a different website. This is why you are not able to finish the codelab.

What you could do is try a more recent codelab such as [this one](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-slack-bot/index.html#0) to practice with Node.js